# Однородные/неоднородные определения

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Хлеб, вырабатываемый по ГОСТ 2077 формовым(,) штучным(,) массой 0,73–1,0 кг из муки пшеничной обойной" можно ли определения "формовым", "штучным", "массой 0,73-1,0 кг" рассматривать как однородные. По Розенталю Д. Э. "однородные определения могут характеризовать предмет с разных сторон, если в условиях контекста они объединены каким-либо общим признаком", в данном случае - это внешний вид. Однако также написано, что между определениями можно вставить союз "и", а здесь, на мой взгляд, как-то он не очень смотрится. Или лучше рассматривать эти определения как неоднородные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однородность или неоднородность таких определений зависит  от классификации, причем надо знать терминологию.

Например, хлеб бывает **подовый** (выпекаемый без специальной формы) и **формовой**, а формовой делится на **весовой и штучный**. Вот между этими видами может стоять союз И, если указываются (**перечисляются**) оба сорта, например: подовый **и** формовой или формовой весовой **и** штучный.

А вот формовой штучный ( или формовой весовой) - неоднородные определения, между ними не ставится запятая. Это **неоднородные признаки**, они оба относятся  к **одному сорту хлеба**, характеризуя этот сорт с разных сторон.

Также мука бывает обдирная (очищенная) и обойная (грубого помола, с отрубями, зародышами и др.)

Предложенный вариант лучше записать так: Хлеб из муки пшеничной обойной, формовой штучный массой 0,73-1,0 кг, вырабатываемый по ГОСТ 2077.

Проверить запись можно, взяв этот ГОСТ, чтобы убедиться в неоднородности определений (в этом случае они относятся **к одному сорту хлеба)**.

Comment: Спасибо. А почему нужно ставить запятую после в предложении, который Вы представили как вариант: Хлеб из муки пшеничной обойной, формовой.  И правильно ли будут расставлены запятые в таком варианте:  "Хлеб, вырабатываемый по ГОСТ 2077 из муки пшеничной обойной формовым штучным массой 0,73–1,0 кг "

Comment: Вообще-то для окончательного решения нужно видеть всю фразу, но мне по стилю не очень нравится выражение "вырабатываемый  формовым....", синтаксис кажется неподходящим для данного текста.

Comment: Полное предложение: Хлеб пшенично-ржаной формовой - хлеб, вырабатываемый по ГОСТ 2077 формовым штучным массой 0,73–1,0 кг из муки пшеничной обойной, ржаной обойной, получаемых в готовой смеси или раздельно (это определение на основе ГОСТа)

Comment: Да, в виде определения звучит нормально, это общепринятые по данной теме формулировки.